# how to position UILabels in ios6?

Tags: iphone, ios

I think the 2 labels, the bigger one and smaller one are just positioned at the centre of the screen. 
Changing the coordinates doesnt seem to have an effect on where they are getting placed. Why?

Ideally I would want them to be of same size, not overlap and one below the other so that they cover nearly the whole screen.

I thought the labelframe uses the format - starting coodinates, size.
Where is my origin? is at top left of the screen?
can I translate it in xcode?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label1;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(-200.0f,0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    //self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.label.text = @"One two three four five six seven eight nine.";
    self.label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:28.0f];
    self.label.numberOfLines  = 5;
    self.label.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.label];

    CGRect labelFrame1 = CGRectMake(600.0f,600.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
    self.label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame1];
    self.label1.text = @"One 1 two three four five six seven eight nine.";
    self.label1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f];
    self.label1.numberOfLines  = 0;
    self.label1.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.label1];



}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Origin 0,0 is the top left corner of the <strike>screen</strike> superview. If you want the labels at the center of the screen, one on top of the other, you can do :

```
self.label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
// setup label text, font..
[self.label sizeToFit]; // automatically set the appropriate size
self.label.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:self.label];

self.label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
// setup label text, font..
[self.label sizeToFit]; // automatically set the appropriate size
self.label1.center = self.view.center; // set at center of screen
// just overwrite origin.y to set it below the previous label
self.label1.frame = (CGRect) { self.label1.frame.origin.x, self.label.frame.origin.x + self.label.frame.size.height, self.label1.frame.size };
[self.view addSubview:self.label1];
```

Update: based on your comment, to have it two rows, one column is easier. Just set the frame to be full width, and half height :

```
self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGrectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height / 2];
self.label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height / 2];
```

Comment: The origin 0,0 is relative to the subview's parent view, not the screen. The center of the screen and the center of `self.view` are not likely the same location.

Comment: I basically want the two labels to be like a matrix of 2 rows and 1 column, one below the other, so that they cover the whole screen

Comment: user494461 I edited my answer to do this. @rmaddy I also corrected the origin thing. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You're overwritting the origins you set when you call

```
self.label.center = self.view.center
```